# Loop in Pandas faster

Tags: python, pandas

I need to make a loop in pandas faster. It's a time series.
Below code works pretty well but it is slow for massive df.

It iterates through a df and at each first value 0 'zero' of column A (it needs to be only the first zero of a serie; df has many 0 series) calculates the delta (in absolute value) of column B values at one period before and after of the initial value 0 'zero' of column A.
Then it stores the results in a new df with column called 'Delta'

I bet I can do something with loc. but I cannot figure out how.

```
deltas=[]
indexes = []
i=0
for idx, row in df.iterrows():

    if df.A[i] == 0 and df.A[i-1] !=0:
    
        deltas.append(abs(df.B.shift(periods=1)[i] - df.B.shift(periods=-1)[i]))
        indexes.append(idx)
        
    i+=1
s_delta = pd.Series(deltas, name="Delta", index = indexes)
df_delta = s_delta.to_frame()
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: Hard to tell without sample data but something like this should work (if I got the logic correct): `df['Delta'] = np.where((df['A'] == 0) & (df['A'].shift() != 0), abs(df['B'].shift(1) - df['B'].shift(-1)), np.nan)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely the result are numbers like these 12.936795711517334, 13.505966663360596. Many of them. As many as the zero series in the df. They are delta values. The result is alredy correct. I need make the loop faster using some built-in funtion in pandas I guess

Comment: @ganesa75 Can you put sample data (cca. 8-10 rows) to your question + expected result to have some data to play with?

Comment: @It_is_Chris it works! thanks so much. Super fast with numpy.

Comment: @ganesa75 no problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use assign function to process df in series not per row:

```
df = df.assign(
    n = lambda x: x.B.shift(1),
    p = lambda x: x.B.shift(-1),
    s_delta= np.abs(x.n-x.p)
)
```

Then you can modify it using np.where